# Vertical align not working CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'am trying to verticaly align my page, but I just cant get it to work.
I've tried other solutions from other questions, but none of them worked for me so far, does anyone know why?

This is the HTML code I want to align vertically:

```css
    header {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 600px;
      margin-bottom: 3em;
      margin-top: 3em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    section {
      width: 600px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 3px;
      background-color: white;
    }
    #textbox {
      color: #075488;
      border: solid 3px #075488;
    }
    #textbox div {
      font-weight: bold;
      border-bottom: 2px solid #075488;
      margin-left: 3em;
      margin-right: 3em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 2em;
      padding-top: 1.5em;
      padding-bottom: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #textbox table {
      font-weight: normal;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 5em;
      padding-left: 4em;
      padding-bottom: 1em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      line-height: 1;
    }
    td:nth-child(3) {
      width: 100px;
    }
    td:nth-child(2) {
      text-align: center;
    }
    section p {
      color: white;
      font-size: 12px;
      float: right;
    }
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img src="images/image.png">
</header>
<section id="section">
  <div id="textbox">
    <div>test</div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Thanks you!

If CSS isn't possible is it possible to use jQuery/Javascript instead, if so how would I go abouts doing so?

Comment: Define "Align vertically". What do you want to be aligned with respect to what?

Comment: I want that the header/section center vertically so the margin-top from the header is the same as the margin-bottom from the section

Comment: Are you asking how to make the *entire page* render in the middle of the window?

Comment: yes i want the full body content in the middle vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `position: absolute` on your `body`, and center it via:

```
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Safari */
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);         /* Other browsers */
}
```

*(remember to remove top margin on header)*

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
section {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}
#textbox {
  color: #075488;
  border: solid 3px #075488;
}
#textbox div {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #075488;
  margin-left: 3em;
  margin-right: 3em;
  padding-left: 2em;
  padding-right: 2em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
#textbox table {
  font-weight: normal;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 5em;
  padding-left: 4em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 1;
}
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}
td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}
section p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x50">
</header>
<section id="section">
  <div id="textbox">
    <div>test</div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use vertical alignment you have to provide heights to your elements. Your elements currently do not have a set height, so their height is the minimum that will contain their contents, and thus they do not stretch to your page height

Answer (score 0):

You can just say:

```
td {text-align: center}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k30se3fv/3/